# The difference about WPCN and TDMA or FDMA

Tags: digital-communications, multiplexing

I am a little bit confused about the difference WPCN and TDMA or FDMA,i mean the level difference.

WPCN is a wireless powered communication network,as the name implies,it can transmit the information without wire,so is it a transmitted technology or a transmitted paradigm?TDMA and FDMA are the method that transmitt information by dividing frequency and time.

What i really want to ask is that do them just like that i know a method which can transmit signal without wire,and i called this method "WPCN",and in this method,WPCN, i use TDMA or FDMA to transmit information,am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDMA and FDMA are paradigms; they provide different methods for sharing communications resources between multiple users.  WPCN is a technology for using wireless communications resources, and can be used with TDMA or FDMA depending on the particular application, though neither is "best suited" to the technology.